# Как оптимально посчитать сколько раз встречается в тексте каждое слово?

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация

Частотный анализ – 1. Условие:

Дан текст на русском языке. Посчитайте, сколько раз встречается в тексте каждое слово.

Слово — это последовательность русских букв. Кроме слов, в тексте могут присутствовать пробелы и знаки препинания («,», «.», «!», «?», «:» и «;»). Других символов в тексте нет.

Слова необходимо сравнивать с точностью до регистра. То есть «Привет» и «привет» — это одно и то же слово, а вот «рыба», «рыбы» и «рыбу» — три разных.

Формат ввода:
В первой строчке задано одно целое число N (1 ≤ N ≤ 1000) — количество строк в тексте. В следующих N строках приведён сам русский текст. Текст состоит из русских букв, пробелов и знаков препинания: «,», «.», «!», «?», «:» и «;». Длина текста не превышает 100 000 символов.

Формат вывода:
Выведите слова исходного текста, упорядоченные по убыванию количества их попаданий в текст. В случае, если два слова встречаются в тексте одинаковое количество раз, выведите их в лексикографическом порядке.

Каждое слово нужно вывести в отдельной строке. Первая буква слова должна быть заглавной (даже если она не была заглавной в исходном тексте), остальные — строчными.

**Пример**

Ввод:

```
2
Ехал Грека через реку. Видит Грека в реке рак.
Сунул Грека руку в реку, рак за руку Греку цап.
```

Вывод:

```
Грека
В
Рак
Реку
Руку
Видит
Греку
Ехал
За
Реке
Сунул
Цап
Через
```

В учебных целях не надо использовать функции, импорт модулей, классы. Решить задачу надо используя множества, списки, словари и их методы.

У меня получился такой код:

```
words_dict = {}
sentences1 = [input().split() for i in range(int(input()))]
sentences = [j.strip('!?:;,.').capitalize() for i in sentences1 for j in i]
for i in sentences:
    words_dict[i] = words_dict[i] + 1 if i in words_dict else 1
keys = list(words_dict.keys())
values = list(words_dict.values())
for i in range(len(keys) - 1):
    for j in range(len(keys) - i - 1):
        if keys[j] > keys[j + 1]:
            keys[j], keys[j + 1] = keys[j + 1], keys[j]
            values[j], values[j + 1] = values[j + 1], values[j]
for i in range(len(keys) - 1):
    for j in range(len(keys) - i - 1):
        if values[j] < values[j + 1]:
            values[j], values[j + 1] = values[j + 1], values[j]
            keys[j], keys[j + 1] = keys[j + 1], keys[j]
print('\n'.join(keys))
```

Он пе проходит по времени, при вводе 900 строк код выполняется за 1.089 секунд моё решение не принимают, ограничение по времени 1 сек. Помогите, пожалуйста, как-нибудь сократить код или найти более оптимальное решение данной задачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я бы делал это приблизительно так:

ввод:

```
N = int(input())
text = " ".join(input() for _ in range(N))
```

или **менее читабельный**, но более короткий вариант:

```
text = " ".join(input() for _ in range(int(input())))
```

подсчет слов:

```
res = {}    
for word in text.strip(",.!?:;").lower().split():
    res[word] = res[word] + 1 if word in res else 1

for word,cnt in sorted(res.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])):
    print(word.capitalize())
```

---

вывод:

```
Грека
В
Рак
Реку
Руку
Видит
Греку
Ехал
За
Реке
Сунул
Цап
Через
```

Comment: strip('.,!?:;')

Comment: тогда, наверное еще делить по дефису надо было бы

Comment: @splash58, даже не знаю... стоит ли делить слово `все-таки` на `все` и `таки`

Comment: ну да. я тоже не знаю

Comment: @splash58, [вот](https://chgk.livejournal.com/1787193.html) - решил проверить... ;) В общем, скорее это надо считать одним словом и поэтому ваш вариант вполне валиден

Comment: А что такое lambda?

Comment: Ну да, тогда таблица исключений нужна :)

Comment: @TAWER768, это безымянная однострочная функция - является синтаксическим сахаром

Comment: Я посмотрел, вроде бы strip() это не встроенный метод, это из какого-то другого модуля?

Comment: это встроенный метод строк

Comment: @TAWER768, https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip Попробуйте запустить: `print("Где знак вопроса?".strip("?"))` ;)

Comment: @MaxU Вышла такая неловкая ситуация, я ещё не проходил функции... Я поменял программу (Обновил вопрос) и всё равно я выхожу за рамки поставленного времени. :( Наверное, дело в том, что у меня в коде очень много вхождений в цикл

Comment: @TAWER768, я функции не писал - только пользовался встроенными... Но если в задании нельзя использовать встроенные функции, то вам придется как-то обходиться без функций `input()`, `range()` и без методов класса `str` - таких как `.split()`, `.capitalize()`, `.join()`. ;) Думаю решение в этом случае будет супер громоздким и ооооочень медленным

Comment: @MaxU Я имею в виду lambda, def. А не такие, которые вы указали.

Comment: @MaxU Извините, я просто никак не могу понять, что тут делает функция лямбда? Какую функцию она выполняет?

Comment: @TAWER768, попробую дополнить ответ когда доберусь до компьютера